# Vue 3 - Object property is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

How can I make `userInfo.value.email` reactive in the following Vue3 component:

```
<script setup>
  import { useUserStore } from '../store/user';
  import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
      
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  const { userInfo } = storeToRefs(userStore)

  const page = {
    formData: {
      email: userInfo.value.email    <<<<<<===== How can I make this reactive?
    },
    submittingForm: false,
    submitForm() {
      console.log(this.formData)
    }
</script>

<template>
  <form name="emailForm" @submit.prevent="page.submitForm">
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <div>
        <input id="email" v-model="userInfo.email">   <<<<<===== This input field is reactive with the store
      </div>
    </div>
    <button>
      Continue
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

`userInfo.value.email` represents the initial value from `useUserStore` but if I change the value in the input form of the template and then submit, the value in the input form reverts back to the initial value before it is submitted as confirmed by `console.log(this.formData)`.

In case this helps, here's my store:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {
  const userInfo = ref({
    email: ""
  });
  ...           
  return { userInfo }
},{
  persist: true
});
```

**Example**

1. "initialEmail@gmail.com" is the initial email presented in the email field as it is stored in localStorage as well as the `email` property of `userInfo` object in the store (as depicted in the Vue dev tool):

[image]

2. "updatedEmail@gmail.com" is the revised email entered in the email field.  This field is reactive as indicated by the updated `email` property of `userInfo` object in the store (as depicted in the Vue dev tool):

[image]

3. Clicking the Continue button causes the value in the email field of the form and `email` property of `userInfo` object in the store to revert back to "initialEmail@gmail.com".  Additionally, the email value submitted is also "initialEmail@gmail.com" as confirmed by the devtools console:

[image]

Thanks!
-Vee

Answer (score 0):

There is a `reactive` fn to create reactive objects in Vue3

```js
import {reactive} from "vue"
const page = reactive({
    formData: {
      email: userInfo.value.email    <<<<<<===== How can I make this reactive?
    },
    submittingForm: false,
    submitForm() {
      console.log(this.formData)
    }
})
```

Ref: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the same issue.  When I submit the form, `this.formData` contains the original value presented in userInfo.value.email instead of the updated value.  I'll add an example in my question to clarify.

Comment: How would you access `formData` from `this`. It's inside the object `page`. IMHO, it should be like: `this.page.value.formData`

Comment: My thought was that the v-model binds in the input field to the store via `userInfo.email`.  Therefore, the updated email in the input field would be reflected in the store and also `page.value.formData.email`.  What would be the better way to 1) Present the initial email stored in localStorage and 2) Submit an updated email?

Comment: Also, `console.log(this.page)` is `undefined` which IMHO makes sense bc `page` is a property of the component and `formData` is a key of the reactive `page` object.  Wouldn't `this` refer to the object `page` since it's being used inside the object method, `submitForm`?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. ;) Since you can use `userInfo.email` in the input field, I do not see any more useCase of `formData` in the code other than in the Submit Function. If that is the single useCase, maybe declaring it as a const inside the Submit Function might make things easier. While constructing it every time inside the SubmitFunction with reactive `userInfo` the `const ` will be also in sync.